# Is there easier way to unmarshall dynamodb attribute value

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

`{ L:[{ N: "123"}, { N: "543"} ]}`

Is there an easy way to unmarshal such dynamodb attribute values

Answer (score 0):

There are no double quotes around the keys (L,N) hence you won't able to unmarshal them using json.unmarshal function. you can try following way to unmarshal the mentioned json string.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Response struct {
    L []InnerElement `json:"L"`
}

type InnerElement struct {
    N string `json:"N"`
}

func main() {

    st := `{L:[{ N: "123"},{ N: "543"}]}`
    st = strings.Replace(st,"N",`"N"`,2)
    st = strings.Replace(st,"L",`"L"`,1)

    var res Response

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(st), &res)

    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Print("error with json unmarshaling")
    }

   //print value
   fmt.Println(res.L)


}
```

Replace the key with double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the [aws-sdk-go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/) package and that output comes from a scan or query result. If so, the subpackage [dynamodbattribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/) provides unmarshaling utility to convert `dynamodb.AttributeValue` to your struct:

```golang
// var result *dynamodb.ScanOutput

// This can be a list of struct too, but your sample output looks like a list of numbers.
nums := make([]int, 0, *result.Count)
if err := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(result.Items, &nums); err != nil {
    // handle error
} else {
    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```

Comment: Do you think UnmarshalList will work for GetItem function/method of the DynamoDB?

Comment: No, it won't work for GetItem. You might want to check the `dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap` function instead